# Classic ASP / Round() - Show Numbers 10,000+ as 10K

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Like on Stack Overflow's reputation points, if a number is greater than ten thousand, they show it as 10.3K, to save space. Do I achieve this using the Round function or is better to use some kind of string manipulation?

Comment: Sounds like a little bit of division is in order.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: is that what Stack Overflow is for; so amateurs can post questions that can be mocked by the experienced? It's not very encouraging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [`FormatNumber()`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp) to shorten the number when necessary, here's some sample code to demonstrate:

```
<%
' Number scale I used:
' http://www.statman.info/conversions/number_scales.html
Function shorten(s)
    Dim i, f

    i = CDbl(s)

    If (i > 1000000000000) Then
        i = i / 1000000000000
        f = "T"
    ElseIf (i > 1000000000) Then
        i = i / 1000000000
        f = "G"
    ElseIf (i > 1000000) Then
        i = i / 1000000
        f = "M"
    ElseIf (i > 1000) Then
        i = i / 1000
        f = "K"
    End If

    shorten = FormatNumber(i, 2) & f
End Function

Response.Write shorten("1346578977987") & "<br>"
Response.Write shorten("1645112877") & "<br>"
Response.Write shorten("1313333") & "<br>"
Response.Write shorten("108977") & "<br>"
%>
```

Comment: +1 for the technique although your math is a little off where Mega is concerned.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - Oops, you're quite right. Fixed it now and added giga as well.